# Proving a logic riddle in Coq : testing equivalence in an Inductive set

Tags: coq, beginner

I'm trying to formalize in Coq the following riddle and its solution

> Alice, Bob and Charlie are one of each role:
>
> - a truth teller (always tells the truth)
> - a liar (always lies)
> - and a spy (can lie or tell the truth)
>
> They make the following statements:
>
> - Alice: I am not a truth teller.
> - Bob: I am not a spy.
> - Charlie: I am not a liar.
>
> What role is Charlie?
> A. Truth teller
> B. Liar
> C. Spy
> D. There is not enough information

I could progress alone , up to a point reached in the [following file](https://gist.github.com/johan-buret/b7499d0b867d0ae81da7ef3618e025d4), because I cannot introduce the fact that two distinct roles are not equal to each other.

I tried a `rewrite S in L` as last step but I do not know which tactic to use next.I'm pretty sure there is something basic I'm missing.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

The tactic `discriminate`(https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proofs/writing-proofs/reasoning-inductives.html?highlight=discriminate#coq:tacn.discriminate )  is made to handle  the cases such as `L: spy = liar`

Comment: In this case `congruence` also works, and you don't need to use the `rewrite` command beforehand.